# es6 arrow function doesn't work with switch statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

No error but I can't get my function triggered. Tried to put my exec_request function above or below the switch statement but still no luck.

```
exec_request = (url) => {
    alert('test') // not execute here?
}

switch(list_type) {
    case 'temp': {
        const url = `/shops/spaces/${temp}`;
        exec_request(url)
        break;
    }
    default: {
        const url = `/shops/${shop_id}/spaces`;
        exec_request(url)
    }
}
```

```js
const list_type = '';//'temp';

const temp = "tmp";
const shop_id = "123";

const exec_request = (url) => {
    alert(url) // not execute here?
}

switch(list_type) {
    case 'temp': {
        const url = `/shops/spaces/${temp}`;
        exec_request(url)
        break;
    }
    default: {
        const url = `/shops/${shop_id}/spaces`;
        exec_request(url)
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Please create a concrete example.

Comment: maybe `this.exec_request(url)`? Since you tagged this with [tag:reactjs]

Comment: @Dan You comment is the answer as well .

Comment: Your snippet worked. what is the issue?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to call `this.exec_request(url)`.

Since you tagged this with [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) and `exec_request` is not an global function.